# drop-down menu in accordion, want to make selection without changing panel of the accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, accordion

I have a drop down menu inside an accordion (on the outside portion of it). I want to be able to make a selection on any of the drop down menus without the accordion changing to the panel that that drop down menu is on.

[image: Screen shot]

Full files [download - dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5s35a6jmbeya9jz/tzK31YNk6z)

Comment: Can you post http://www.jsfiddle.net?

Comment: not exactly sure how to make the accordion look right on there (http://jsfiddle.net/DQSH4/). I used someone's plugin for the horizontal accordion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuLxu/).

I've changed your `id` to `class` for your `<select>` elements and put this:

```
$('.selectOne').click(function(){
    return false;
});
```

Hope it helps.